# extending java.lang.String in groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, groovyscriptengine

i've a rather complex problem. I'am currently developing a [a little groovy based script language](https://github.com/mrothenbuecher/groovyfo-ESDK) for an ERP System. The functions and syntax of "my" script language are based on the already existing old [FO language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) which is used by the erp system.

Therefore: I'am getting values from the ERP with calls like `h.fieldname`, where `h` the currently selected dataset is and `fieldname` the name of the field I want my field value from.
I get the field value e.g. of type String. What I now want is to extend these strings I retrieve with a few functions, which are based on the "old" syntax.

```
// some samples
// get last 3 characters 
h.fieldname >> 3
// get first 4 characters
h.fieldname << 4
// should still work even if h.fieldname, returns something which extends String but is not a String
assert h.fieldname == "Foo"
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to make use of the answer of @daggett, here my approach:

```
public abstract class BaseScript extends Script implements GroovyObject {
    
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        Object o = null;
        try {
            final ExpandoMetaClass metaClass = new ExpandoMetaClass(String.class, false, true);
            
            //Closure c = { int x-> delegate[-x..-1] };
            
            //ClosureMetaMethod foo = new ClosureMetaMethod​("rightShift ", c , doCall);
            
            
            metaClass.initialize();
            
            o = runCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.onerror(e);
        } finally {
            this.always();
        }
        return o;
    }

    public abstract Object runCode();

    public Object always() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public Object onerror(Object ex) {
        if (ex instanceof Exception) {
            Exception e = (Exception) ex;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

But honestly i've no idea how to implement it and I also can't find any example.

**UPDATE 2 and solution**

Based on the answer of @daggett.

```
package groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang;

import groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;

public class StringMetaClass extends DelegatingMetaClass {

    public StringMetaClass(Class<?> theClass) {
        super(theClass);
    }

    public StringMetaClass(MetaClass metaClass) {
        super(metaClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invokeMethod(Object object, String name, Object[] args) {
        // implementiert "test" >> 3
        if (name.equals("rightShift")) {
            if (args.length == 1) {
                if (args[0] instanceof Integer) {
                    String str = object.toString();
                    int x = ((Integer) args[0]).intValue();
                    if (str.length() > x) {
                        return str.substring(str.length() - x);
                    }
                    return str;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong argument type, should be integer");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("too many arguments");
            }
        }
        // implementiert "test" << 3
        if (name.equals("leftShift")) {
            if (args.length == 1) {
                if (args[0] instanceof Integer) {
                    String str = object.toString();
                    int x = ((Integer) args[0]).intValue();
                    if (str.length() > x) {
                        return str.substring(0,x);
                    }
                    return str;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong argument type, should be integer");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("too many arguments");
            }
        }
        else {
            return super.invokeMethod(object, name, args);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't extend string class because it's final, however in groovy you can add new methods to string class with help of metaclass

```
String.metaClass.rightShift = { int x-> delegate[-x..-1] }

"1234567890" >> 3
```

returns

```
890
```

in the same way implement the method `leftShift` for `<<`

the last request (`assert s1==s2`) is not relevant because String is a final class (not extendable)

Comment: A huge thank you :). Is there any way to include this in my baseclass (written in java)?

Comment: magic package is a good approach: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_magic_package or use `GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().setMetaClass( String.class, new DelegatingMetaClass(Relationship.class) {...} )`

Comment: the magic package, works fine! Thank you very much!!!